# 75 to 100% of CPU Usage in WPF?

Tags: wpf, performance

Whenever application loads and any other usercontrol loads in the application, while loading and rendering the cpu usage touches 80 - 100%. How should i resolve this?
Thanks and regards,
Ershad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using a lot of CPU power and memory.

Try to find the bottleneck by using a profiler (such as [ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)) to profile for speed and memory usage. After that, optimize the bottleneck by rewriting the algorithm.

Of course, you should test on a new, powerful machine to make sure that it is a really your application problem, but not a my-machine-is-old-and-lousy problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case seems to be WPF event handling.