# WPF Application takes too much CPU for some users

Tags: wpf, performance

I have a WPF application written in VS2010 Express for .Net 4. Some testers report that the application takes alot of CPU (~80%-100%) whenever the application window is visible and 0% when not visible. This is not the case on my computer, nor on the other computers i have tested. What I see is that it takes a bunch of CPU for the first few seconds after opening the window, but then goes down to a few percent.

My suspicion is that this is an issue with the rendering of the WPF window. But i can not understand why it only occurs for some users.

I understand that this is not much to go on, but if anyone have an idea where to start looking for the cause of this performance issue, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have heavy visual customization? What are the OS of faulting computers? On the faulting computers, is the GPU integrated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [75 to 100% of CPU Usage in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159921/75-to-100-of-cpu-usage-in-wpf)

Comment: The only "heavy" customization i have (i guess) is some transparency. I have the issue on one XP and one Vista machine. I understand that if you have an integrated GPU you would get high CPU, but wouldn't it go down after a while, when it has rendered the window. WPF does not re-render the entire window on every frame, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question led me to the right solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler

I profiled the app and removed bottlenecks detected by the profiler. This reduced CPU load on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

With the [WPF Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) you can observe the rendering process of you application relatively detailed.
Perforator (of the toolkit) has helped me in the past a lot for finding performance bottlenecks.